# Simplify Absolute Value in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I currently have a large expression with many terms of the form

```
Abs[-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]]]
```

I know, from the geometry of my problem, that

```
-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]] > 0
```

However, when I try to simplify my expression,

```
Simplify[Abs[-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]]], -2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]] > 0]
```

I just get back

```
Abs[-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]]]
```

How can I make Mathematica simplify out the unnecessary absolute value?

**EDIT 1**

The full expression which I'm trying to simplify is

```
-(1/(2 (m - Tan[\[Theta]])))
 Sqrt[1 + m^2] (B2 Sqrt[(-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B4 Sqrt[(-2 b + 2 d2 m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B5 Sqrt[(2 b + 2 d3 m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B7 Sqrt[(2 b + 2 d4 m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B1 Sqrt[(2 b - 2 (d1 + l) m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B3 Sqrt[(2 b - 2 (d2 + l) m + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B6 Sqrt[(-2 (b + (d3 + l) m) + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2] + 
    B8 Sqrt[(-2 (b + (d4 + l) m) + l Tan[\[Theta]])^2])
```

The terms being squared under each of the radicals is known to be a positive real number.

Comment: The expr now does not contain an Abs - is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.  I've included the original Sqrt terms, which simplify will reduce to Abs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the terms are all known to be real and positive, squaring and taking the square-root will only give you the same number. Hence, you could do something like

```
expr /. Sqrt[(x___)^2] :> x
```

where `expr` is your giant expression above.

Comment: As a practical matter, I've done as you suggest.  However, I was curious if there was a better way to handle it, in case I ever get a mixed expression where only _some_ of the radicals can be safely cancelled out.

Comment: plus one +1 for giant

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ideas:

1)

```
Simplify[Abs[-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]]], 
 0 < \[Theta] < \[Pi]/2 && l > 0 && 2 d1 m > 0 && -2 b > 0]
```

2)

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
Simplify[Abs[-2 b + 2 d1 m + l Tan[\[Theta]]], -2 b + 2 d1 m + 
   l Tan[\[Theta]] > 0, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

Th complexity function f makes Abs more expensive than Times. See docu for Simplify. Does that help?

Comment: Both solutions worked on the term in isolation, but not when it was part of the full expression.  I'm going to add the full expression to my question to hopefully make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to remove specific instances of absolute value, you could do something along these lines:

```
Clear[removeAbs]
removeAbs[expr_, r_] := expr /. {Sqrt[r^2] :> r, Abs[r] :> r}
```

That way it only removes the absolute value from any expressions you specify:

```
In: removeAbs[Abs[x] + Abs[y], x]
Out: x + Abs[y]
```

I'll see if I can find a nicer looking solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm constantly stimied by things like `Abs[a]^2`, and stuff like using `Assuming` with `a\[Element]Reals` doesn't help.

I found some help here [WolframMathWorld - Absolute Square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteSquare.html) with 
 `ComplexExpand[Abs[a]^2, TargetFunctions -> {Conjugate}]`, but sometimes it still returns stuff like `Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]` and I've found wrapping a second `ComplexExpand` (without parameters) around that helps.